# In Beamer, gray out \tableofcontents items already shown on previous frames

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I've got a motivation slide preceding my table of contents slide. So when I show the audience the structure of the remainder of my talk I'd like the `\tableofcontents` to show the motivation slide in gray. The motivation slide is not in the same section environment as the toc slide (and all the following slides).

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, `\tableofcontents[currentsection]` ([Beamer User Guide](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), section 10.5) is critical here. The first two frames are shown below, the remaining two frames aren't really relevant.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\section{Motivation} % may be removed, not sure if you really need a section for this or not.
\begin{frame}[plain] % could make it a normal frame, too.
Here's a motivation slide
\end{frame}


\section{Main Contents}
\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}

\subsection{A Subsection}
\begin{frame}
Something for the subsection
\end{frame}

\subsection{Another Subsection}
\begin{frame}
Something for the next subsection
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, you really helped me out! I used your solution a bit differently though: I put the motivation in a section, the outline in an unumbered section (`\section*`) and the remainder as is. But used two parts to split everything following the outline from the outline and everything preceeding it. Then, I used the following two commands to create the outline: `\tableofcontents[currentsection]\tableofcontents[part=2]`