# beamer table of contents shade all previous sections

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

How do I shade in a LaTeX beamer only the previous sections but not the following sections?

Just right now I have something like

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\section{Section1}
\section{Section2}
\tableofcontents[currentsection] 
\section{Section3}
\frame{}

\end{document}
```

which leads to a TOC which highlights Section2 and shades the other sections [image: Highlighting only Section2].
The desired behaviour would be to highlight Section2 and Section3 and shade only Section1

Comment: Does [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37339/13034) help?

Comment: Or [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40983/13034)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40983/13034) gave me the clue (thanks to @AndrewUzzel).
Splitting in two parts and using two tocs solved it, however spacing needs to be adjusted.
Here is the miminal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\part{one}
\section{Section1}
\part{two}
\section{Section2}
\frame{
\tableofcontents[part=1,currentsection]\tableofcontents
}
\section{Section3}
\frame{}

\end{document}
```